# Automated web UI testing in Node.js

Tags: unit-testing, testing, node.js, automated-tests

Are there any automated web testing libraries for Node.js, preferably headless?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) is a headless full-stack testing framework for Node.js.

There's a [full list of testing modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-testing) on the Node.js GitHub wiki.

Answer (score 5):

You should also check out [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org). Together, it's a testing framework in pure JavaScript with a headless WebKit browser. It works in Linux, OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Selenium now has JavaScript bindings for Node.js.  You can use a headless driver along with the Selenium bindings. ([Check out ghostdriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver).)

Basically all you have to do is install Node.js, set up your driver and then get your Selenium module with `npm selenium-webdriver`.

I have some more detailed instructions and screenshots [in my tutorial, here](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2014/02/03/selenium-with-node-js/).

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) can use headless mode with a configuration for Chrome:

```
let { Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver')
let {Options} =require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')

let options = new Options()
let driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(options.headless()).build()
```

By the way, you can also use [CukeTest](http://cuketest.com/) for writing your UI automation script.